# Repository pattern with changing data on server over time

Tags: android, repository-pattern, restful-architecture, data-layer, clean-architecture

I am following **Clean Architecture** proposed by famous **Robert C. Martin**. The birds eye view of Clean Architecture looks like as follows:

[image]
However right now my concern about **Repository pattern modification**. Basics steps of Repository pattern are:

> 1. Search in-memory cache AND provide data to app layer
> 2. If not found, search local data source AND sync to in-memory cache AND provide data to app layer
> 3. If not found, search remote data source AND sync to local data source AND provide data to app layer

**Following above steps strictly, if a data exists in local data source it will never sync from remote data source while data might be changed in remote. How can I modify so that this case could be handled ? One idea comes in my mind written below, but I am looking to a better solution indeed.**

My idea is to keep track of last sync time for each record in local database. If last sync time is more than a threshold time ago, then sync automatically.

Comment: Maybe you should skip number 3 from your Repository responsibilities You could subscribe to remote data source notifications instead and update your local store whenever changes happen.

Comment: @MaxSC How to implement subscription for remote data source changes for a particular set of data ? My remote server built upon node js.

Comment: Have a look at [firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) and it seems like there are a lot of npm packages that wrap it up [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push).... But I never used one of those :)

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is in compliance with what we are using with a help of RxJava:
[Dan Lew nicely explained at](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/)